# Gitlab CI: How do I make `rules.changes` to compare changed file to main branch?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a base image for my repo that is optionally re-built when branches (merge requests) make changes to dependencies.

Let's say I have this pipeline configuration:

```
stages:
  - Test
  - Build

variables:
  - image: main

Changes A:
  stage: Test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - path/to/a
  script:
    - docker build -t a .
    - docker push a
    - echo 'image=a' > dotenv
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: dotenv

Build:
  stage: Build
  image: $image
  script:
    - echo build from $image
```

Let's say I push to a new branch and the first commit changes `/path/to/a`, the docker image is build and pushed, the dotenv is updated and the `Build` job successfully uses `image=a`.

Now, let's say I push a new commit to the same branch. However, the new commit does not change `/path/to/a` so the `Changes A` job does not run. Now, the `Build` stage pulls the "wrong" default `image=main` while I would like it to still pull `image=a` since it builds on top of the previous commit.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

- Is there a way to make `rules.changes` refer to `origin/main`?
- Any other ideas on how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to make `rules.changes` refer to `origin/main`?

Yes, there is, since [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#improved-behavior-of-cicd-changes-with-new-branches) (August 2022):

> ### Improved behavior of CI/CD changes with new branches
>
> Improved behavior of CI/CD `changes` with new branches
>
> Configuring CI/CD jobs to run on pipelines when certain files are changed by using `rules: changes` is very useful with merge request pipelines.
> It compares the source and target branches to see what has changed, and adds jobs as needed.
>
> Unfortunately, `changes` does not work well with branch pipelines.
> For example, if the pipeline runs for a new branch, `changes` has nothing to compare to and always returns `true`, so jobs might run unexpectedly.
>
> In this release we’re adding `compare_to` to `rules:changes` for both jobs and `workflow:rules`, to improve the behavior in branch pipelines.
>
> You can now configure your jobs to check for changes between the new branch and the defined comparison branch.
> Jobs that use `rules:changes:compare` will work the way you expect, comparing against the branch you define.
>
> This is useful for monorepos, where many independent jobs could be configured to run based on which component in the repo is being worked on.

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/293645).

> You can use it only as part of a job, and it must be combined with rules:changes:paths.

Example:

> ```yaml
> docker build:
>  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
>  rules:
>    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
>      changes:
>        paths:
>          - Dockerfile
>        compare_to: 'refs/heads/branch1'
> ```
>
> In this example, the docker build job is only included when the `Dockerfile` has changed relative to `refs/heads/branch1` and the pipeline source is a merge request event.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project setting, which defines how your MR pipelines are setup. This is only working for Merge requests and can be found in `Settings -> Merge Requests` under the section `Merge options`

[image]

1. each commit individually - nothing checked

   this means, each commit is treated on its own, and changes checks are done against the triggering commit on it's own
2. Enabled merged results pipeline

   This will merge your MR with the target branch before running the CI Jobs. This also will evaluate all your changes, and take a look at all of them within the MR and not commit wise.
3. Merge trains

   This is a whole different chapter, and for this usecase not relevant. But for completeness i have to mention it see https://gitlab.com/help/ci/pipelines/merge_trains.md

What you are looking for is Option 2 - `Merged pipeline results`. but as i said, this will only work in Merge Request pipelines and not general pipelines. So you would also need to adapt your rules to something like:

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - path/to/a
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Comment: Is there a way to see this setting without having sufficient permissions to change it? I would like to know if this is the source of my problems but can't see the option...